# Implicit interface based on class

Tags: c#

I have a lot of classes in my business layer that have an interface which must always have the same methods and properties as the public methods and properties of my business class. This is a common scenario, as the interface is needed for dependency injection and mocking while unit testing.

It would be optimal if I could somehow define the interface as the same as the public methods and properties of a class. That way I don't have to copy paste method definitions from my implemented class to my interface all the time. I don't see any logical problem with this, but I know that it's not directly possible to do in C#.

Perhaps someone can come up with a reasonable way to accomplish this?

Here is an example. Here is an interface.

```
public interface IAccountBusiness
{
    Guid GetAccountIdByDomain(string domain);

    void CreateAccount(string accountType, string accountName);
}
```

Here is the implementation:

```
public class AccountBusiness : IAccountBusiness
{
    public Guid GetAccountIdByDomain(string domain)
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    public void CreateAccount(string accountType, string accountName)
    { 
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

If I want to add a parameter more in CreateAccount, for example "Email", then I have to add it to both the interface and the business class. In this example it's a minor nuisance but in larger scale projects it's ... well ... still a minor nuisance, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Care to add some code to better explain your question?

Comment: have you seen the refactoring options of visual studio yet? in the pro version, there is an option for creating an interface class, and the auto completion has a feature to implement all members of an interface

Comment: Resharper is having such features. You may try it.

Comment: OK, I've provided an example. It's not the initial creation of the class but the daily maintenance of methods and parameters.

Comment: Hmm I quite like this idea, having a think about any pitfalls and there doesn't seem to be anything major. I suppose it would be possible to write an addon for VS that creates them automatically for all classes that you decorate with an attribute, there's a nice Sunday afternoon project for someone!

Comment: Yes, that's one way to go. I was also hoping someone knew about some rarely used language feature that could make an interface 'inherit' from a class.

Comment: @DavidG - what are you talking about? What is this "idea"?

Comment: It is **very** important that you do this the other way around.  Since in very large projects, you can't make the assumption that changing one class method is enough.  You *must* change the interface method first.  And then the compiler tells you about any implementation method you might have overlooked.  This can only be done properly by the tool between your ears, tools like Resharper don't know how to write code to use the added/changed argument properly.

Comment: Hans, I understand what you mean. I'm just pointing out the reality that most projects have some sort of main implementation of an interface and the interface might as well be based on that. Like AccountBusiness is obviously the main implementor of IAccountBusiness so the definition of IAccountBusiness is bound to be the same as AccountBusiness. Then other classes deriving from IAccountBusiness would fail if they don't keep up.

Comment: @samuel-liew, thank you for your attention on this question. This question was asked more than 6 years ago and there was no fitting answer. Now Microsoft has actually implemented this feature in the C# language and I thought it was a fitting answer for the question and thought I was doing a good deed by providing an answer for this old question. However, you deleted my answer. Could you let me know what was wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

[`Resharper's`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) `Change Signature` refactoring allows you to do that easily:

[image]